# How to check if multiple columns are valid percentages (not negative numbers or numbers greater than 1)

Tags: r

I am trying to check if multiple columns of a data frame have valid percentages. That is, no negative numbers or numbers greater than one.

I have provided an example of my data below using the dput() function.

```
structure(list(fightName = c("UFC Fight Night: Makhachev vs. Moises", 
"UFC Fight Night: Makhachev vs. Moises", "UFC Fight Night: Makhachev vs. Moises", 
"UFC Fight Night: Makhachev vs. Moises", "UFC Fight Night: Makhachev vs. Moises", 
"UFC Fight Night: Makhachev vs. Moises"), redFighterName = c("Alan Baudot", 
"Francisco Figueiredo", "Amanda Lemos", "Daniel Rodriguez", "Khalid Taha", 
"Gabriel Benitez"), redFighterHead = c(0.75, 0.57, 0.85, 0.8, 
0.27, 0.66), redFighterBody = c(0.16, 0.25, 0.14, 0.04, 0.36, 
0.22), redFighterLeg = c(0.08, 0.17, 0, 0.15, 0.36, 0.1), redFighterDistance = c(0.6, 
0.64, 0.85, 0.84, 0.9, 0.77), redFighterClinch = c(0.31, 0.14, 
0, 0.02, 0.09, 0.1), redFighterGround = c(0.08, 0.21, 0.14, 0.13, 
0, 0.12), redFighterResult = c("W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W"), 
    blueFighterName = c("Rodrigo Nascimento", "Malcolm Gordon", 
    "Montserrat Conejo", "Preston Parsons", "Sergey Morozov", 
    "Billy Quarantillo"), blueFighterHead = c(0.83, 0.86, 0.66, 
    0.6, 0.9, 0.73), blueFighterBody = c(0.12, 0.04, 0.33, 0.17, 
    0.04, 0.2), blueFighterLeg = c(0.04, 0.08, 0, 0.21, 0.06, 
    0.07), blueFighterDistance = c(0.91, 0.47, 1, 1, 0.66, 0.61
    ), blueFighterClinch = c(0.08, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.12, 0.11), blueFighterGround = c(0, 
    0.41, 0, 0, 0.22, 0.28), blueFighterResult = c("L", "L", 
    "L", "L", "L", "L")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to check if redFighterHead, redFighterBody etc (which all contain percentage data) have valid percentages. That is, no occurrences of negative numbers or numbers greater than 1.

Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Comment: Can you please provide a real example of your data: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also, are you talking about checking several columns or several rows (as in your example)?

Comment: @deschen I have fixed my example and made it closer to my actual data frame. And I am checking several columns and several rows. Basically, in all columns that record % data, I just need to ensure all of them are between 0 and 1.

Comment: Ok, but it would be really helpful if you could still provide a small example of your data by using dput(df) or if your df is too large use dput(head(df))

Comment: @deschen Updated using Str() function. The dput(head(df)) gave me an output in a weird format.

Comment: But this weird dput output is exactly what we need! Just copy the output from teh console into your question.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update after TO provided reprex:

I would do sth. like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  select(where(is.numeric)) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~all(. >= 0 & . <= 1)))
```

This gives you the info which column satisfy your condition and which don't. Also note that I used a condition >= 0 and <=1, instead of >0 and <1, because 0 and 1 are valid percentages!

Another note: I only checked numeric columns on your condition and left our character columns.

```
  redFighterHead redFighterBody redFighterLeg redFighterDistance redFighterClinch redFighterGround blueFighterHead blueFighterBody blueFighterLeg blueFighterDistance
1           TRUE           TRUE          TRUE               TRUE             TRUE             TRUE            TRUE            TRUE           TRUE                TRUE
  blueFighterClinch blueFighterGround
1              TRUE              TRUE
```

If you just want to print the general info about your data, you could wrap this code into your if condition and using `all`:

```
if (all(df %>%
          select(where(is.numeric)) %>%
          summarize(across(everything(), ~all(. >= 0 & . <= 1))) == TRUE)) {
  print("df has no values less than 0 or greater than 1")
} else {
  print ("df only has values between 0 and 1")
}
```

Additional note: your current print statements are basically the same. The first statement says that all elements are between 0 and 1, and the second statement has exactly the same.

---

OLD:

Assuming your data is called df and your column Percentages you can do:

```
if (all(df$Percentages > 0 & df$Percentages < 1)) {
  print("df has no values less than 0 or greater than 1")
} else {
  print ("df only has values between 0 and 1")
}
```

Comment: The code still says 'df only has values between 0 and 1' despite the -1 and 3 values.

Comment: See my updated answer @JChan22

Comment: I'd upvote if I could, thank you very much!

Comment: No worries. If the solution works, you can accept (which you did), which is most helpful for others when having a similar problem.